# Silverlight: is there a way to allow a user to open a file from isolated storage?

Tags: .net, silverlight, webdav

I'd like to allow a user to open files in their own client applications via Silverlight. I'd like this to work similarly to WebDAV, in the sense that they could read/write the file back into Silverlight's isolated storage...

Is it possible to construct a file:// link to an isolated storage file?
Is there a uri scheme that is defined for silverlight in a browser that has the silverlight plugin?

Am I totally nuts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this and there is a tutorial on it [here](http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2007/10/12/silverlight-tutorial-using-isolated-storage/). The tutorial is just on how to use isolated storage, but the example is to open files on the user's system and store them in isolated storage. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the inverse of what I am trying to do, which is to push a file into Isolated Storage from some other remote location, and then allow a user to open that file for edit, when they click save, I want Silverlight to upload the changes back to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is unfortunately not directly supported today. However, with Silverlight 3's release last month, you will find that there is now a FileSaveDialog.

Combined with isolated storage, the FileOpenDialog, and FileSaveDialog, you do have some options for creating a system for providing files to your users, and receiving their updates.

However, they'll need to initiate the open and save - the actual isolated storage file paths are pretty difficult to discover, and it isn't recommended to allow users direct access to them.